# regex for matching column names on a matrix

Tags: regex, r

I'll have two strings of the form

1. "Initestimate" or "L#estimate" with # being a 1 or 2 digit number
2. " Nameestimate" with **Name** being the name of the actual symbol. In the example below, the name of our symbol is "6JU4"

And I have a matrix containing, among other things, columns containing "InitSymbol" and "L#Symbol". I want to  return the column name of the column where the first row holds the substring before "estimate".
I'm using stringr. Right now I have it coded with a bunch of calls to str_sub but its really sloppy and I wanted to clean it up and do it right.
example code:

```
> examplemat <- matrix(c("RYU4","6JU4","6EU4",1,2,3),ncol=6)
> colnames(examplemat) <- c("InitSymb","L1Symb","L2Symb","RYU4estimate","6JU4estimate","6EU4estimate")
> examplemat
     InitSymb   L1Symb      L2Symb      RYU4estimate 6JU4estimate 6EU4estimate
[1,] "RYU4"     "6JU4"      "6EU4"          "1"          "2"           "3" 
> searchStr <- "L1estimate"
```

So with *answer* being the answer I'm looking for, I want to be able to input examplemat[,*answer*] so I can extract the data column (in this case, "2")

I don't really know how to do regex, but I think the answer looks something like

```
examplemat[,paste0(**some regex function**("[(Init)|(L[:digit:]+)]",searchStr),"estimate")]
```

what function goes there, and is my regex code right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try:

```
library(stringr) 
Extr <- str_extract(searchStr, '^[A-Za-z]\\d+')
Extr
[1] "L1"

#If the searchStr is `Initestimate`
#Extr <- str_extract(searchStr, '^[A-Za-z]{4}') 

pat1 <- paste0("(?<=",Extr,").*")
indx1 <-examplemat[,str_detect(colnames(examplemat),perl(pat1))]
pat2 <- paste0("(?<=",indx1,").*")

examplemat[,str_detect(colnames(examplemat), perl(pat2))]
#6JU4estimate 
#     "2" 

#For searchStr using Initestimate;
#examplemat[,str_detect(colnames(examplemat), perl(pat2))]
#RYU4estimate 
 #    "1"
```

Comment: close! looks like `Extr <- str_extract(searchStr, '(Init)|(^[A-Za-z]\\d+)')` works for the first part without having to "if" it. Also I should note that length(grep("estimate","estimate2"))!=0 is ~19 times faster than str_detect("estimate2","estimate") while accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: @hedgedandlevered.  Yes the first part is probably that.  I was a bit confused about the whole setup.  In general, `grep` should be faster than `str_detect`.

Answer (score 0):

The question is bit confusing so I am quite not sure if my interpretation is correct.

First, you would extract the values in the string "coolSymb" without "Symb"
Second, you can detect if column name contains "cool" and return the location (column index)
by which() statement.
Finally, you can extract the value using simple matrix indexing.

```
library(stringr)
a = str_split("coolSymb", "Symb")[[1]][1]
b = which(str_detect(colnames(examplemat), a))
examplemat[1, b]
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: By naming my symbols the way I did I introduced some ambiguity that makes your answer applicable to my question but not my real question. I'll edit to make it more specific

Answer (score 0):

won782's use of str_split inspired me to find an answer that works, although I still want to know how to do this by matching the prefix instead of excluding the suffix, so I'll accept an answer that does that.
Here's the step-by-step

```
> str_split("L1estimate","estimate")[[1]][1]
[1] "L1"
```

replace the above step with one that gets {L1} instead of getting {not estimate} for bonus points

```
> paste0(str_split("L1estimate","estimate")[[1]][1],"Symb")
[1] "L1Symb"
> examplemat[1,paste0(str_split("L1estimate","estimate")[[1]][1],"Symb")]
     L1Symb
[1,] "6JU4"
> paste0(examplemat[1,paste0(str_split("L1estimate","estimate")[[1]][1],"Symb")],"estimate")
[1] "6JU4estimate"
> examplemat[,paste0(examplemat[1,paste0(str_split("L1estimate","estimate")[[1]][1],"Symb")],"estimate")]
     6JU4estimate
[1,] "2"
```